# why is the color of table not applied to the right-bottom corner?

Tags: html, css

I have this table on fiddle. But the colors are not applied to the bottom-right corner.

**http://jsfiddle.net/5LrEJ/**

**http://i.hizliresim.com/eXDaY0.png**

How can I Fix it? Thanks.

```
<div class="datagrid"><table>
        <thead><tr><th>Rank</th><th>Player Name</th><th>% of Wins</th><th>Total Wins</th><th>Total Losses</th></tr></thead>
        <tfoot><tr><td colspan="4"><div id="paging"><ul><li><a href="#"><span>Previous</span></a></li><li><a href="#" class="active"><span>1</span></a></li><li><a href="#"><span>2</span></a></li><li><a href="#"><span>3</span></a></li><li><a href="#"><span>4</span></a></li><li><a href="#"><span>5</span></a></li><li><a href="#"><span>Next</span></a></li></ul></div></tr></tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>1</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr class="alt"><td>2</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr class="alt"><td>4</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>5</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr class="alt"><td>6</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>7</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr class="alt"><td>8</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr><td>9</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
            <tr class="alt"><td>10</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<tfoot><tr><td colspan="4">
```

To

```
<tfoot><tr><td colspan="5">
```

Your table has 5 columns but your tfoot has 4. By changing colspan from 4 to 5 the bottom right cell is added.

This solves your problem.